# React + Electron How to print HTML?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I am using react and electron. I need to print some generated HTML in react app when I pus click on button:

```
<FlatButton label='Print' primary={true} onTouchTap={this.props.print} />
```

But the problem is, that new window in electron don't have document property, so I can't write there some HTML. New Window i need to preview output data:

```
  print(){
    let win = window.open();

    console.log(win);
  }
```

[new window properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6004.png)
I need something like that

```
let win = window.open();
win.document.write('Some Data');
win.print()
win.close()
```

How can I resolve this problem? Any ideas?

Comment: check this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627064/how-to-print-a-div-in-electronjs) Here you have a example of the flow of electron. change the printPdf event just for print and will work.

Comment: I have been resolved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been resolved the problem. The solution for me: create the print view component and just use window.print() to print the data.